# Proper way of declaring React props in a constructor that are never used

Tags: reactjs, typescript, constructor

Normally, when I don't use `props` in a `construtor`, I can safely leave it as blank

```
constructor() {
    super()
}
```

But TypeScript requires you to define it. If I don't use it, I have been doing something like this:

```
constructor(_: never) {
    super(_)
}
```

Is there a correct and/or more formal way of declaring an argument that you never use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function parameters [can be underscored in TypeScript if they aren't used](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#flag-unused-declarations-with---nounusedparameters-and---nounusedlocals) to avoid compilation error. `_` name is misleading because it doesn't contain information and will clash with other property names if there's more. Since properties are used as `super` arguments, underscoring isn't needed.

`never` is not a correct type here because this means [something else rather than a property that is never used](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never). It may be in conflict with parent constructor parameter types.

```
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    // ...
  }
```

would be a proper way to do this in JavaScript but in TypeScript `super` arguments should be specified explicitly if they are mandatory. Explicit constructor like that can be omitted because this is done by default when no `constructor` is specified.

Explicit constructor is rarely necessary in React components. The only `super` property in effect is `props`. Most initialization code goes to component lifecycle hooks (deprecated [`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) is the only exception) , while instance properties can be declared as class fields in TypeScript:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    foo: synchronousInitialization();
  };

  // isn't needed
  /*
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  */

  async componentDidMount() {
    const bar = await asynchronousInitialization();
    this.setState({ ...this.state, bar });
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would give the parameter its usual name of `props` for clarity and its correct type.  Claiming that it is of type `never` is inaccurate, since `never` is the type that has no values and a value is certainly passed to the constructor at runtime; it's unfortunate that the `never` doesn't result in a compile error based on the particular way TypeScript processes JSX elements.